# Question about reverse triangle inequality for expected values

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Suppose we have random variable $X$ and $Y$ where $Z$. Then using reverse triangle inequality we have that 
\begin{align}
\|X-Y\|_2 \ge  \left|\|X\|_2-\|Y\|_2 \right|
\end{align}
However,  I can come up with an example such that $\|X-Y\|_2<\infty$ but both $\|X\|_2,\|Y\|_2=\infty$. For example, let $Y=X+Z$ where $Z$ is any random variable that has a finite second moment. For example, pick $Z$ such that it is 1 and $X$ is Cauchy distribution.

So, we  can have a case
\begin{align}
1 \ge | \infty-\infty|
\end{align}

Is this a problem? Or we just assume that $| \infty-\infty|=0$.

P.S.  $\|X\|_2=(E[X^2])^{1/2}$

Comment: It is conventional to say that $\infty - \infty$ is undefined, so it doesn't make sense!

Comment: The norm is only defined on $L^2(\Omega)$, so $\Vert X\Vert_2 < \infty$ by definition.

Comment: @WilliamStagner So what you saying is that the statement $||X-Y||_2$ can not be made because before hand $X$ and $Y$ must be show to be in $L_2$?